# fmincg implementation in Python

Tags: optimization, python, machine-learning, octave

I'm trying to re-implement Neural Networks in Python. I implemented the cost function and the backpropagation algorithm correctly. I have checked them by executing its Octave equivalent code.

But when I'm trying to use the `scipy.optimize.fmin_cg` function, the iterations take a very long time to execute. It exits with a warning and gives me an error saying that the "desired error rate wasn't achieved".

The same program in Octave executes fine. However, it has its own `fmincg` function defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: everybody, I got an error'It seems the kernel died unexpectedly" where did I do wrong, is there something else I need to do in order to use the fmin_cg for vectorized calculation?

Comment: To avoid symmetry breaking you should initialize params as: params = numpy.random.randn(dims)*0.01

Answer (score 6):

As a future hint, use the double question mark ?? to pull the source of the function:

Looking at the scipy sources this error message comes up if the internal parameter alpha_k is zero or None.

This value in turn is tied to the internal Wolfe Line search algorithm.  In particular it is called when the search doesn't find a better value along the search trajectory.  Your function likely has a linear contour somewhere along it that the optimizer falls into and gets confused.

Perhaps try adding a callback, and see where the failing search is generated?

Comment: As a follow up to this, scipy picks its max iteration count based on the size of the vector to be optimized.  This is a better than average guess, but ought to be documented more obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you didn't specify the `fprime` parameter. If you don't provide this param `fmin_cg` has to figure out its own solution what usually is much slower than which a provided optimal solution. Your code might look like this:

```
theta = fmin_cg(compute_cost_reg, fprime=compute_gradient_reg,
                x0=theta, args=(X, y, lambd), maxiter=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've just been struggling with a similar issue and thought I'd post my solution incase anyone else comes across this.

I found the problem was that I hadn't properly initialised the $ \Theta $ vector to break the symmetry.

After doing this, I ran `fmin_cg` with f **and** fprime, and although it still ran rather slowly, it did so without any of the errors or warnings I had been seeing up to that point.

In fact, it actually did a better job of minimising the cost function than the matlab implementation, despite both having `max_iters = 100`.